# Basic jQuery banner?

Tags: jquery, banner, rotation

I'm still new to jQuery and come from a flash/javascript background when it comes to banners and dynamic web features. Does anyone know any good tutorials for a simple rotating banner?

I'm looking to build one with 3 rotating images and a 1,2,3 button to go back to other images.

Any help or advise would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You should get familiar with [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

But why reinvent the wheel ? There are so many good and well tested jQuery plugins.

**Plugins**

- [33 POWERFUL JQUERY SLIDESHOW (SLIDERS) PLUGINS AND TUTORIALS](http://www.themeflash.com/30-powerful-jquery-slideshow-sliders-plugins-and-tutorials/)
- [25 jQuery Image Gallery/Slider Tutorials and Plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/)
- [175 Awesome jQuery Slider and Effects Roundup](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/09/jquery-slider.html)

**Tutorials**

- [Create an Image Rotator with Description (CSS/jQuery)](http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/)
- [Simple Banner Rotator with JQuery tutorial](http://www.fmajakovskij.info/simple-banner-rotator-with-jquery-tutorial/)

Comment: Sorry, thought so because you were the only person else who posted something.
Can't see who rated me down, that really pisses me off sometimes...

Comment: No, it was not me. Must be another user. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this function, it's a simple slider:

**HTML**

```
<img src="pic_01.jpg" id="photo" />
<span id="slideNumber"></span>
```

**JS**

```
var ImageArr1 = new Array("pic_01.jpg","pic_02.jpg","pic_03.jpg");
var ImageHolder1 = document.getElementById("photo");

function RotateImages(whichHolder,Start)
{
var a = eval("ImageArr"+whichHolder);
var b = eval("ImageHolder"+whichHolder);
if(Start>=a.length)
Start=0;
b.src = a[Start];
document.getElementById('slideNumber').textContent = "Slide "+(Start+1)+" of "+ImageArr1.length;
window.setTimeout("RotateImages("+whichHolder+","+(Start+1)+")",3500);
}

RotateImages(1,0);
```

I have a picture container and switch it's SRC-attribute to show the other pictures.
It's timed automatically to 3500 milliseconds and shows information about the picture index below.

That's pure javascript I know, but have a look at it. It will teach you some basics.

Comment: I got my banner working finally, thanks for all the post's. I'll also try this code for another rotator I'm doing.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Cycle-plugin is perfect for this

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It even makes a dynamic menu (like 1,2,3-bottons like you wanted).